# How to create a process instance in activiti-app by script?

Tags: activiti

Currently, I only deployed activiti-app in my environment; I can create/run process instance successfully by dashboard, but there's a requirement to create/run process instance by script, e.g. REST API, how to do that?

Someone suggest to start activiti-rest and point to the same database, but it will report table conflict (MySQL).

Refer to the following thread for the detail:

https://community.alfresco.com/message/821342-re-how-to-use-rest-api-with-activiti-app?commentID=821342&et=watches.email.thread

Answer (score 1):

You can post to the activiti-app ReST API:

URL : Request URL:http://localhost:8080/activiti-app/app/rest/process-instances

payload: {processDefinitionId: "myProcess4:47504", name: "My Process - September 20th 2017"}

Greg

Comment: Great; how about authentication?

Comment: Uses Basic Authentication

Comment: Here's the command line: curl http://admin:test@activiti.druid.io/activiti-app/app/rest/process-instances , and here's response: The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource. any suggestion? BTW, I can use admin/test to login the dashboard.

Comment: any suggestion? can you give an example?